# Typescript cannot retain reference to owner class

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out how to keep a reference to the chat class in this situation.  What's the workaround?

```
class chat {
    private self: chat;
    public currentUsers: any = ko.observableArray();

    constructor(public chatService: any) {
        this.self = this;
        chatService.client.receiveUsers = this.receiveUsers;
    } 

    private receiveUsers(users: any): void {
        //'this' has been changed to refer to the external caller context (chatService.client)
        this.currentUsers(users);//fail
        //property currentUsers does not exist on value of type 'Window'
        self.currentUsers(users);//fail
        //currentUsers does not exist in the current scope
        currentUsers(users);//fail
        //There's apparently no way to access anthing in this chat class from inside here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is receiveUsers being called from? I assume something like signalR, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to keep a reference to `this` on the class instance is like putting a sticky note on the remote control that says "Here's where the remote is!" because you keep losing it.

Use a fat arrow lambda expression to capture the lexical 'this' at the callback site:

```
class chat {
    public currentUsers: any = ko.observableArray();

    constructor(public chatService: any) {
        chatService.client.receiveUsers = (users) => this.receiveUsers(users);
    } 

    private receiveUsers(users: any): void {
        // use 'this' here now
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I had a feeling the fat arrow could be used to solve the problem after reading the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077565/setinterval-behaviour-in-typescript this morning, but I couldn't think of what it would take.

Comment: Yup, that worked.  Would you update your answer to match the lambda params to the target method signature?  It doesn't build as you have it now.   `chatService.client.receiveUsers = (users) => this.receiveUsers(users);`

Comment: Done. More characters to make a valid comment.